# Get wcf callback port without specifying it in config file

Tags: c#, wcf, ip-address, wcf-client, firewall

I use `WSDualHttpBinding.ClientBaseAddress` to open port for `callback` in firewall on client side. How can I get port without specifying it in configuration file?

Is there some default port? Or way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

IIS uses port 80 and by default the clientBaseAddress too uses the same port

Anand Kesavan